# App for finding iPhone from a Mac?

Tags: icloud, macos

Is there any Mac client to enable the "Find my iPhone" service? It would be better from the command line, but an app will also do.

None of the programs I have tried seem to work right now.

Answer (score 2):

I use Sosumi: http://clickontyler.com/sosumi/

It is essentially a Mac app version of the iCloud Find My iPhone webpage.  Except it allows you to add multiple iCloud accounts.  So as an example, I added my own so I can track my own iDevices, but I also added my Mom's to track her iPhone if need be.

Comment: Is it working with Mavericks for you? That was one of the apps I tried and since the last change was 3 years ago, I thought it was outdated

Comment: Yup, works fine with Mavericks for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an app. Just log into your iCloud account through Safari or Chrome or any other browser you use.

1) Log into iCloud.com with your Apple ID
2) Click on “Find iPhone” App
3) Here we go: you should be able to see it as long as
--You have your iPhone connected to your Apple ID
--Your iPhone is online and charged

You can also filter view of your devices. Select your iPhone and you can do the following:

1) Turn into lost mode and text to it
2) Erase/Delete the data on it
3) Beam/Play sound so you can hear it if it’s around you

I can't take credit, [this guys wrote it nice](https://www.idropnews.com/discussions/how-to-find-my-iphone-using-mac/39567/).